# PHP include statement begining variable isnt showing

Tags: php

For some reason the first variable just wont display in my code. Am I doing something wrong?

```
$url = 'http://localhost/development/ui';
$filename = 'login';
include_once($url.'/views/app-pages/'.$filename.'.php');
```

I am getting the following error

> PHP Warning:  include_once(/views/app-pages/login.php): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory

Hmm ive tried a bunch of different methods of displaying that var in the begining. Idk why its not working.

If it also helps  the following code is just a simplified version of what I have. My code is actually within a function. But that shoudnt matter the following include statement still isnt working.

Comment: Use a relative path to. If that were the case, it'd be a free-for-all.

Comment: You don't use your URL in your include, you use your file path

Comment: makes since let me try that

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php `include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/lib/sample.lib.php";` - *"So you can move script anywhere in web-project tree without changes."*

Comment: @Fred-ii-: You don't use URLs normally, but yes you can and may need to.  Reloaded...  I see :-)

Comment: @AbraCadaver Which is why I edited my comment; do reload ;-)